# Link Cryptlib Library with Qt creator

Tags: qt, qt-creator, linker-errors, cryptlib

I have Qt Creator 2.6.1 based on Qt 5.0
I have build cryptlib with visual studio 2010

all cryptlib project is on C:\SDK\cl342
when I have built the project the crypt.h and cl32.lib and cl32.dll are in this folder 
C:\SDK\cl342

I am getting linker error on every method that I call from cryptlib such as cryptInit
I have tried adding it from the project menu and add external library it makes many changes to pro file but does not even let me include crypt.h.

mainwindow.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cryptEnd@0 referenced in function "public: __thiscall MainWindow::MainWindow(class QWidget *)" (??0MainWindow@@QAE@PAVQWidget@@@Z) –

my pro files looks something like this.

```
**QT       += core gui
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
TARGET = testlistview
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp
HEADERS  += mainwindow.h
FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
INCLUDEPATH = C:\SDK\cl342\
DEPENDPATH += C:\SDK\cl342\
LIBS += C:\SDK\cl342\cl32.lib**
```

Comment: Please add the linker errors which are shown in Qt Creator (at least one of them).

Comment: mainwindow.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cryptEnd@0 referenced in function "public: __thiscall MainWindow::MainWindow(class QWidget *)" (??0MainWindow@@QAE@PAVQWidget@@@Z)